# Solaris: how to remove profile?

Tags: solaris

Solaris 11 with RBAC,profiles can give some privileges to user(is like sudo but more advanced).

With command

```
profiles -p "profile name"
```

I can create the profile

With command

```
usermod -P "profile name" role/user
```

I can assign the profile to user or role

With command

```
usermod -P -"profile name" role/user
```

I can remove the profile from user.

Which command for delete the profile from system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `profiles(1)` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/profiles-1.html#REFMAN1profiles-1), it appears a form of

```
profiles -p "profile name" delete
```

would remove the profile.  An example from the man page:

> **Example 5 Deleting a Profile**
>
> The following command deletes the User Manager profile from LDAP:
>
> ```
> example% profiles -p "User Manager" -S ldap delete -F
> ```

I don't currently have access to a Solaris 11 instance with profiles to test, though.